# Unable to run PCA from Orange GUI

Tags: python, pca, orange

I am unable to find the [PCA module](http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/widgets/rst/unsupervized/PCA/) in Orange. From the documentation it seems to be present but I cannot find it in the GUI.

I have installed all the addons and I can find PCA in the Orange Python library `orngPCA`.

My Orange version is installed through `pip` and is 2.7.2.

Comment: Is it not under the "unsupervised" tab? Also what is your OS and how are you launching the GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had such problem before. I also had installed orange with pip. It seems orange is very sensitive to the version of the packages it depends on. What I did to make it work was the following (in Windows 7):

1. Uninstall Orange
2. Download the [Orange with Python installer](http://orange.biolab.si/download/files/orange-win-w-python-snapshot-hg-2014-11-30-py2.7.exe)
3. Open the downloaded file with [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)
4. Within 7zip, open the folder "$COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY"
5. There you'll see the package installers. Install, in this order, setuptools, then pyqt, then pyqwt. You probably want to uninstall these through pip before overwriting.
6. Install Orange through the installer.

I know it's ugly, but it was the only way I could make it work without having to uninstall my existing Python installation.